# Script insert statements top 1000 rows in each table in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-data

I am trying to write a script that will generate an dynamic set of insert statements.  Some of the table are really large (80,000,000 rows).

I am looking to populate my development environment from production and I don't have the space to do a full backup and restore.

I want the top 1000 rows of every table.  Not sure have to get into into a combined insert script.

Here is what I have so far...

```
--Select Tables and Columns Names
SELECT t.name,
c.column_id AS column_id,
c.name AS column_name
INTO #TEMP
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
ORDER BY t.name,c.column_id

--Concatenate Column Names into String 
Select distinct ST2.name,
               substring((Select ','+ST1.column_name  AS [text()]
            From #TEMP ST1
            Where ST1.name = ST2.NAME
            ORDER BY ST1.column_id
            For XML PATH ('')),2, 1000) [INSERT]
     INTO #TEMP3
     From #TEMP ST2

--Build being of Insert statement
SELECT 'INSERT INTO dbo.' + t.name + ' (' + t.[INSERT] + ') VALUES ('
FROM #TEMP3 t

--Build Select 1000 from each Table.
SELECT 'SELECT TOP 1000 '''+t.name+''' AS TB_NAME,* FROM dbo.' + t.name
FROM #TEMP3 t
ORDER BY t.name
```

What I am tying to figure out is how to concatenate the actual values that are return from the Select 1000 into INT,VARCHAR, or FLOAT text/number qualified values and then add it to the Insert Statement and output as TEXT...so I can save the file and run it on my development computer.

Any ideas?

Thanks
jlimited

Comment: Do any of your tables have foreign key relationships? If so, especially if there are many-to-one or many-to-many, taking the top arbitrarily ordered 1000 rows isn't necessarily going to work out very well.

Comment: Also, have you considered writing a linked server query, so that your query can simply be `INSERT linked_server.database.dbo.table(col1,col2) SELECT TOP (1000) col1,col2 FROM dbo.table ORDER BY ...;`? Now you don't have to worry about proper concatenation of data types etc. You will have to make sure that destination tables with identity columns either leave out the identity column in the insert, or set `IDENTITY_INSERT` on...

Comment: There are foreign key relationships.  All of which are One to Many.  The parent tables within the foreign key are small in comparison to the larger ones and so i used the generate scripts tool within SSMS to extract those tables (ddl and data).  I grabbed the ddl for the larger tables (but no data).  So I will have all the foreign relationships.  Primary Key are not auto increment Identity columns.